# Google Sign-In on Android failing on all devices except primary debug device

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

For some reason signing into Google does not work on all devices except my daily-driver that I use for debugging. I've even tried installing a debug build on my tablet and that doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
onCreate(){

    ...
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("~webID~.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

@OnClick(R.id.google_signin_button)
public void signInWithGoogle(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

On the not-working devices, when this is invoked onActivityResult is never called. Instead the device returns to the desktop and quits the app. I'm not sure what's going on. Any help?

Comment: What does `logcat` say? Do you have Google Play Services on these devices?

Comment: I actually just figured out the issue. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was having the task labelled with `noHistory` in the manifest. Why this was an issue or why it affected different devices differently I don't know. Either way, removing that fixed the issue.

Comment: Makes some sense: if you start another activity, it won't be able to return to a `noHistory` activity because it doesn't exist anymore. That doesn't explain why it worked on *one* of your devices, though… :-?

Comment: @ephemient I think what was going on was on newer devices the sign in was achieved in a popup of sorts, whereas older devices considered the sign-in a separate activity.